# How do I retrieve the JWT token in C#?

Tags: c#, jwt, azure-active-directory

I retrieve an `id_token` from AzureAD which I can see in inspect element.

I am simply trying to retrieve the token in C# so I can decrypt it but I am unable to do so.

I have tried:

```
var authHeader = Request.Headers["id_token"];
var authHeader = Request.Form["id_token"];

JwtSecurityToken token = new JwtSecurityToken(authHeader);
```

Both return null.

Comment: What authentication mechanism are you using?

Comment: openIdAuthentication and oAuth token

Comment: Which azure ad sample did you refer to? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-aspnet-webapp

Comment: Yes, the same as that

Comment: My sso is set to use SAMl2. Can I send a openId request despite this?

Comment: @Echodaa I am not familiar with SAMI2, you can post a new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the id token by override `OnSecurityTokenReceived` method.

Add custom `OnSecurityTokenReceived` to the `Notifications`.

```
Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                {
                    AuthenticationFailed = OnAuthenticationFailed,
                    SecurityTokenReceived= OnSecurityTokenReceived
                }
```

Then you can get id token like this

```
private Task OnSecurityTokenReceived(SecurityTokenReceivedNotification<OpenIdConnectMessage, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions> context)
        {
            var idtoken = context.ProtocolMessage.IdToken;
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }
```